# App paused on Splashscreen. Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to run my game on a Iphone 6. Build process is completed but after load the game, I received the following error on **DisplayManager.mm** file, **line:** **return self[targetScreen] !=nil;**

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (code=1,address=0xc).**

[DisplayManager.mm file is here.](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/attachments/69425-displaymanager.zip) 
I don't see any error on the debugger log. **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting is set to YES**

I can see the Icon on my iphone, but the game crash after loading. I exported this game from Unity 5.7 and I'm running on XCode 7.3

Any recommendations are welcome, Thanks

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate all plugins, rebuild the project from scratch and try adding the plugins one by one. If that still doesnt work deacrivate any byte code stripping, enable exceptions and use the MONO scripting backend instead of LLVM. (for testing)